# Proof of polynomial kernel using positive semi-definiteness

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, kernel-trick

I was asked to prove that $K$ is a valid kernel: $K(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) = \sum_{i=0}^M {a_i(G(\vec{u}, \vec{v}))^i}$ with $a_i \ge 0$, given that $G$ is a valid kernel.

I tried to prove it using symmetry and positive semi-definiteness. For symmetry, it's trivial, but for positive semi-definiteness:

> **Positive semi-definiteness :** $\sum_{i=j}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_i a_j K(x_i, x_j) \ge 0$ for any datapoints $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and any values $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb R.$

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=j}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_i a_j K(x_i, x_j) &\ge 0\\
\sum_{i=j}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_i a_j \left(\sum_{k=0}^M {a_k(G(\vec{u}, \vec{v}))^k}\right) &\ge 0\\
\end{align*}
$$
But I do not know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You did not properly substitue $K(x_i,x_j)$ in your expression. Do the proper subsitution and try to exploit the fact that $G$ is semi positive definite.

Comment: @StratosFair, I figured it out. Thanks so much!